# How can I rewrite my specific functions to be compatible with multiple events

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

I have multiple containers with content blocks within them. I've got two a functions that activate by clicking on a button left or right of the container which will scroll it left or right. These two functions work fine for the first container but since I've got four more of these containers that I want to be able to scroll there has to be a simpler way to write these functions to be compatible with all five containers.

I could always copy and paste the same code four more times but that makes for very ugly and redundant code because the only thing that changes is the class of the container that has to be scrolled.

I'm hoping some more experienced front-enders would be able to help me rewrite these functions. I'm not as advanced of a coder so I'm struggeling coming up with a good solution.

Also another problem is that the functions that make the scrolling possible aren't entirely my own code. I found most of it online somewhere and only altered it slightly to make it work for my website. So I'm not exactly sure how all of these statements work, only roughly.

As a possible solution I thought maybe have an array that stores the class names of the containers and have them be pasted in where I do .querySelector to get the class. But sadly I couldn't get that to work the way I wanted it to.

```html
<!-- example code -->
<div>
      <h1>Container title</h1>
        <div>
         <button id="scrollLeft1" type="button">&#60;</button>
          <div class="container">
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 1</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 2</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 3</figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
         <button id="scrollRight1" type="button">&#62;</button>
        </div>
</div>
<div>
      <h1>Container title 2</h1>
        <div>
         <button id="scrollLeft2" type="button">&#60;</button>
          <div class="container">
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 1</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 2</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="some image" alt="">
                <figcaption>Test 3</figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
         <button id="scrollRight2" type="button">&#62;</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

```js
var buttonOne = document.querySelector("#scrollLeft1");
var buttonTwo = document.querySelector("#scrollRight1");
var buttonThree = document.querySelector("#scrollLeft2");
var buttonFour = document.querySelector("#scrollRight2");

function scrollRight() {
                var container = document.querySelector(".container");
                scrollAmount = 0;
                var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
                    container.scrollLeft += 10;
                    scrollAmount += 10;
                    if(scrollAmount >= 700){
                        window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
                    }
                }, 5);
            };

function scrollLeft() {
                var container = document.querySelector(".container");
                scrollAmount = 0;
                var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
                    container.scrollLeft -= 10;
                    scrollAmount += 10;
                    if(scrollAmount >= 700){
                        window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
                    }
                }, 5);
            };

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", scrollLeft);
buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", scrollRight);
buttonThree.addEventListener("click", scrollLeft);
buttonFour.addEventListener("click", scrollRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a version of your code which should be reusable between the different containers and also left some comments for better understanding of what is going on.

```js
// create an array with all buttons that scroll left
var leftScrollButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#scrollLeft1, #scrollLeft2, #other-btn-id, .other-btn-class");

// create another array with all buttons that scroll right
var rightScrollButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#scrollRight1, #scrollRight2, #other-btn-id, .other-btn-class");

// create a default configuration object
var configDefault = {
  direction: 1, // use 1 for right, -1 for left
  amount: 10,
  interval: 5,
  threshold: 700
}

// scrolling function will use the configuration object for the information that it needs
function horizontalScroll(configObj) {
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  scrollAmount = 0;
  var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
    container.scrollLeft += configObj.amount * configObj.direction;
    scrollAmount += configObj.amount;
    if(scrollAmount >= configObj.threshold){
      window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
    }
  }, configObj.interval);
}

// will iterate over every item of the array (all buttons) and add a click event listener to them
leftScrollButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var container = ev.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.container');
  // from the default configuration object, overrite what you need, in this case, the direction property
  var configLeft = Object.assign({}, configDefault, {direction: -1, container: container});
  horizontalScroll(configLeft);
  debug("Scrolled left", container); // used only for the demo
}));

// will iterate over every item of the array (all buttons) and add a click event listener to them
rightScrollButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var container = ev.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('.container');
  // from the default configuration object, overrite what you need, in this case, no need to overrite anything here
  var configRight = Object.assign({}, configDefault, {container: container});
  horizontalScroll(configRight);
  debug("Scrolled right", container); // used only for the demo
}));

// only used for the demo
function debug(action, container) {
  var actionSpan = document.querySelector('.action-span');
  actionSpan.innerText = action;
  var containerSpan = document.querySelector('.container-span');
  containerSpan.innerText = container.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText;
}
```

```html
<!-- to test the demo -->
<p>Last action: <span class="action-span"></span></p>
<p>Container: <span class="container-span"></span></p>

<!-- example code -->
<div>
  <h1>Container title</h1>
  <div>
    <button id="scrollLeft1" type="button">&#60;</button>
    <div class="container">
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 1</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 2</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 3</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <button id="scrollRight1" type="button">&#62;</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Container title 2</h1>
  <div>
    <button id="scrollLeft2" type="button">&#60;</button>
    <div class="container">
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 1</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 2</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="some image" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test 3</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <button id="scrollRight2" type="button">&#62;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```